# How to use enums to determine if two things are equal then, and return a related value

Tags: java, enums, enumeration

So I didn't really know how to word this in the title. I'm working on a program that reads code, then returns whether all the bracket symbols are balanced by putting them in a linked list. if not balanced it would return that there was a mismatch, the symbol expected, and the symbol read.

This is my code for the enum:

```
public enum bracketsEnum {
  parenthesis('(',')'),
  square('[',']'),
  curly('{','}');

private final char open,close;

bracketsEnum( char _open, char _close){
    open=_open;
    close=_close;
}
public char getOpen(){
    return open;
}
public char getClose(){
        return close;
}
}
```

I was thinking of letting the program check if the current character is part of the enum, and if it matches the other set symbol move on, if not, it returns the expected symbol.

I've already figured out the list part, and how to sort and check the symbols. However, I'm kindda lost on the enums, and I'm not sure where to go from here. All the enum tutorials I found were pretty vague, and I'm beginning to doubt if using enums is actually a a good idea.

Also, is using enums in this situation a good idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to implement the solution without Enum.

Then see if it gives you anything if to use Enum (very little if any).

Comment: @Slava I can see why in his current impl it doesn't give him much, but IMO using an enum can let you have 'MetaData' on a specific value through members ('isEndMark','isValidInsideOfMethod' etc...), a strong attribute when this code gets more features in it...

Answer (score 0):

Enum comes with method public final int compareTo(E o) where you can compare to enums.

If you don't want to compare the enums then you can write your own menthod inside enums for comparision and call this method.

Enums are also has all the Object properties.

```
public enum bracketsEnum {
parenthesis('(',')'),
square('[',']'),
curly('{','}');

private final char open,close;

bracketsEnum( char _open, char _close){
open=_open;
close=_close;
}
public char getOpen(){
   return open;
}
public char getClose(){
    return close;
}
//Write your own comparision logic method here

}
```

Comment: So would you suggest using enums in this situation, or would it be less efficient?

Comment: I would suggest using stack for this. As soon as you get open bracket push it to the stack and once you get the closing bracket pop the item from stack. If a correct open bracket is not popped then you have a mis match. At the end if no items present in the stack code has correct open and close bracket.